# Single rowset in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I m stuck at this place. I m trying to get a single rowset value in a variable.

```
DECLARE @last_timestamp as varchar;
SET @last_timestamp = SELECT MAX(modify_timestamp) FROM dbo.table1
PRINT @last_timestamp
```

It is returning the below error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Is Cursor the only solution to this problem. Any help would be helpful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @last_timestamp as varchar;
SELECT @last_timestamp  = MAX(modify_timestamp) FROM dbo.table1
PRINT @last_timestamp
```

or

```
DECLARE @last_timestamp as varchar;
SET @last_timestamp  = (SELECT MAX(modify_timestamp) FROM dbo.table1)
PRINT @last_timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @last_timestamp := MAX(modify_timestamp) FROM dbo.table1
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(modify_timestamp) INTO @last_timestamp FROM dbo.table1
```

or

```
SET @last_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(modify_timestamp) FROM dbo.table1)
```

Comment: Very thorough, although I've never used the := operator.  To the googles!

Answer (score 0):

You can place parenthese around the `SELECT` statement

```
DECLARE @last_timestamp as varchar;
SET @last_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(modify_timestamp) FROM dbo.table1)
PRINT @last_timestamp
```